# Q&A plugin does not show on PHPBB forum

Tags: php, forum, phpbb3

I'm working on a PHPBB 3.0.9 forum using a theme named forum_7589. There's a captcha protecting the registration form but it has been useless against human spamming. So I've been asked to change the captcha plugin & set it to 'Q&A'. (formerly : previous image).

I found the configuration form in the backend, changed the settings to 'Q&A' and saved the changes. The plugin is configured for the good language (fr, here). It has a question and a set of answers registered.

Unfortunately, although it shows OK in the admin screen, it is not displayed at all in the registration form. Instead, part of the old captcha displays : I see the input for the security code (not the image).

I have cleaned the cache (templates & themes) in the backend and my browser.

I did some search and found that this could be a theme issue. I should have to update some files of the theme. I 've taken a look at the *forum/styles* folder and noticed that 3 files : *captcha_default.html, **captcha_qa.html** and captcha_recaptcha.html* were present in the *subsilver/templates* folder but not in the *forum_7582/templates* subdirectory. I copied them from one folder to the other, cleaned caches etc.

Without success.

I'm a PHP developer but I know nothing about PHPBB architecture. I have no idea of what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And yes, before you ask : I'm not allowed to upgrade to v3.0.11 and I'm not allowed to change the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out eventually.

In case it could help somebody later :

I have updated the *styles/forum_7582/template/ucp_register.html* file : the section following the line with `<!-- END profile_fields -->` was not the same than the one in the subsilver theme. I replaced it with the the subsilver code for the said section :

```
<!-- IF CAPTCHA_TEMPLATE -->
        <!-- INCLUDE {CAPTCHA_TEMPLATE} -->
```

Cleaned caches.

The Q&A shows at least, and works fine.